# Como verifico se um arquivo existe no meu hd usando php? (Linux)

Tags: php, linux

Tenho uma aplicação php que irá ler arquivos de retorno do banco, para isso, preciso saber se o arquivo existe no hd do sistema.

Tentei da seguinte maneira: `if(file_exists("/caminho/do/arquivo/".$retorno))`, 
a variável `$retorno` contem o nome do arquivo com a extensão correta. Quando executo minha aplicação pelo shell do linux (php retorno.php), ele entende que todos os arquivos existem, mas quando verifico a pasta, ela está vazia.

O que pode estar dando errado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso acontece porque a função `file_exists` verificar se um arquivo ou diretório existe. E como você disse que a pasta existe mas está vazia, a função sempre vai retornar `true`. Para resolver isso é só você utilizar a função `is_file`.

```
if (is_file("/caminho/do/arquivo/{$retorno}")) {
   // Sua lógica aqui...
}
```

Comment: `is_file` já não verifica se o arquivo existe?

Comment: Você está correto @AndersonCarlosWoss, editei a resposta. Vlws!

Comment: Funcionou! Obrigado!